# Install VisualEditor extension on MediaWiki

Tags: server, mediawiki, plugin, vpn

I have migrated my website from a shared hosting to VPS in order to enable the [VisualEditor extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor) on my MediaWiki website but I am not able to make it work.

Firstly, I have installed the Parsoid service, and I think it is working, as I can see http://example.com:8000 and I can render a page from http://example.com:8000/localhost/PageName.

Secondly, I have installed VisualEditor for MediaWiki 1.24, as I have upgraded to MediaWiki 1.24.1, and I have configured it to connect to http://example.com:8000 and "localhost".

I think that the setup is right because when I click on "edit", from the shell, I see that the rendering starts and finishes. However, the only thing I see is the progress bar indicating that the VisualEditor interface is loading and it doesn't change.

From what I see, I think that Parsoid is properly installed but I don't know if the problem is with the VisualEditor extension or some other extension/configuration/whatever is preventing the VisualEditor interface from loading. I have tried to disable all other extensions and the situation is the same. With a previous installation (MediaWiki 1.23.6 and the VisualEditor for 1.23 with Parsoid extension was the same).

Comment: See [the MediaWiki debugging tutorial](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug) and your browser's documentation about using the web developer console (e.g. [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)). It is unlikely that anyone can help you without as much as an error message.

Comment: @Tgr With Firefox's console I can see that the "Edit button" is making a call and gets a 200 OK answer with code. From what I am seeing and reading, I suspect that it is a JavaScript problem. However, no JavaScript errors are notified in the console.

Comment: @user1314836, you should open the request response and see its full content. HTTP 200 means nothing with MediaWiki API, there might be an error message inside.